# PreparedStatement won't send data over to database

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I'm unsure as to why my program won't actually send the data supplied over to the table in my database table. I'm using a JavaFX application table to select a client from the table when selected and when signed in, the method sends the info to the `DBconnect` class to perform the operation.

Method to send the data to the `DBconnect` class:

```
public void signIn() throws SQLException {
    BloomClient person = clientList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    dBconnect.sendToRoster(person.getFirstName(),person.getLastName());
}
```

Method to perform `PreparedStatement`:

```
public void sendToRoster(String fName, String lName) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement st = c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO sign_in_roster VALUES(?,?,?,?);");
    c.setAutoCommit(false);
    try {
        st.setString(1,fName);
        st.setString(2,lName);
        st.setString(3, systemDate());
        st.setString(4, systemTime());
        c.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not executing the statement.

st.executeUpdate()

Answer (score 3):

You've set all the bind variables, but you've forgot to execute the statement:

```
st.setString(1,fName);
st.setString(2,lName);
st.setString(3, systemDate());
st.setString(4, systemTime());
st.executeUpdate(); // Here
c.commit();
```